# Hackerrank Contest: Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was going through a contest problem on hackerrank (link below)

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w13/challenges/a-super-hero

It is as far as I know, a dynamic programming problem. I tried various approaches, but failed to clear it. Its has a lengthy problem statement, but I will try to explain it as short as possible.

You have to clear **n** different levels, each containing **m** enemies. Each level can be cleared by defeating **any one enemy** of that level. Each enemy has **some bullets and some power**. You need as many bullets as his power to defeat him. After you defeat a enemy, you take his bullets, which **can be used only at next level**. So, you have to tell, **minimum no. of bullets** required at the start to complete the game.

For more details, please see the link.

Complete solution is not necessary. Just some pointers, tips will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this problem is not DP. It is a binary search problem. Do a binary search over the answer. For each number of bullet N, be **greedy** on each level. That is, out of the enemies that you can kill(i.e. have power no more than your current bullets), kill the one that will give you the most bullets **after the end of the level**. Note that here you need to subtract the number of bullets you will need to kill the given enemy. If the initial value N is enough to complete all levels you set it as the new end of the range you are searching in. Otherwise set N as the new beginning(regular binary search approach).